# How can I predicate an array dictionaries to find matching value

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary, search, nspredicate

I have the following dictionary:

```
let object = [[String : AnyObject]]()
/*
{  
"allProducts":[  
  {  
     "productDetails":[  
        {  
           "productName":"My product which I am unable to get by NSPredicate."
        }
     ]
  }
]
}
*/
```

I want to predicate to get the "productName".

Code tried:

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "productName CONTAINS[c] '\(text)'")
arrayTableData = allProducts.filter() { predicate.evaluate(with: $0["productDetails"]) }
```

Comment: Can you write the contents of your `object` using swift syntax? I can't read JSON

Comment: 'object' will have the commented JSON object.

Comment: I know, but I'm bad at read JSON...

Comment: Please copy paste the object in https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to (and shouldn't) use `NSPredicate` for something this simple.

```
arrayTableData = allProducts.filter() { product in
    return product["productDetails"]?.contains { details in
        return details["productName"]?.contains(text) ?? false
    } ?? false
}
```

Comment: But 'productDetails' has an array of dictionaries, and the dictionary has a key "productName".

Comment: wait, each productDetails is an array of dictionaries with a single key:value pair each? ... why?

Comment: The response is more elaborate, I have just written the value that needs to be extracted.